# flutter : english not working with the arabic fonts

Tags: flutter

iam using a custom arabic font for my app

but sometimes the data that coming from the server come in english

the problem is that the custom arabic font not changing the english 
letter font to the main font like what is happening in android

i used the localization to determine the language of the app but it didnt success

because i think that the app language didnt change

its just the letters

so i think if i could determine the language of the text then choose the font for it

or using a font that supporting arabic or english

but is there any better solution?

thank u

Comment: Have you got any answer ?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: use ASCI code to determine the language